# Array List Help Cheat Engine

Tags: lua, cheat-engine

I am looking for a way to make a array list in cheat engine does anyone know how to make one? I have attempted to make scripts to no success.

Comment: Please provide more details and show us some code. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Use Lua's table type to create arrays/lists

```
local myPetList = {"dog", "cat", "bird"}
```